# Connecting to Mpos Device throws java.nio.channels.IllegalBlockingModeException

Tags: java, android, android-studio, bluetooth, nio

I'm trying to develop an  Android application  which connects to mPos device and is able to perform a successful payment .In the first step, I'm trying to connect via Bluetooth and I've succeeded to pair the smart phone with the mPos,but when I try to get the terminal information which is returned from the API provided by the producer of the device ,I receive the following exception.I don't have any idea about it and I really need to solve this problem!!!

```
java.nio.channels.IllegalBlockingModeException
```

The code which I receive the mentioned exception after its execution is the following:

```
base.beep();
sn = base.readSN();
```

base is an instance of a class which is in the API

Please help me solve this issue.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found the solution myself,
there was something wrong while setting the connection type property on the device.
Thanks a lot

Comment: can you describe your solution more?

Comment: This answer is not at all useful. Either (1) describe your solution in detail in the answer and edit your question so that the answer makes sense or (2) delete the question. Ping me after you've edited your answer and question, so I can remove my downvote.